# Doesn't C# Extension Methods allow passing parameters by reference?

Tags: c#, vb.net, extension-methods, byref

Is it really impossible to create an extension method in C# where the instance is passed as a reference?

Here’s a sample VB.NET console app:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    Dim workDays As Weekdays

    workDays.Add(Weekdays.Monday)
    workDays.Add(Weekdays.Tuesday)

    Console.WriteLine("Tuesday is a workday: {0}", _ 
      CBool(workDays And Weekdays.Tuesday))
    Console.ReadKey()
  End Sub
End Module

<Flags()> _
Public Enum Weekdays
  Monday = 1
  Tuesday = 2
  Wednesday = 4
  Thursday = 8
  Friday = 16
  Saturday = 32
  Sunday = 64
End Enum

Module Ext
  <Extension()> _
  Public Sub Add(ByRef Value As Weekdays, ByVal Arg1 As Weekdays) 
    Value = Value + Arg1
  End Sub
End Module
```

Note the Value parameter is passed ByRef.

And (almost) the same in C#:

```
using System;

namespace CS.Temp
{
  class Program
  {
    public static void Main()
    {
      Weekdays workDays = 0;

      workDays.Add(Weekdays.Monday); // This won't work
      workDays.Add(Weekdays.Tuesday);

      // You have to use this syntax instead...
      // workDays = workDays | Weekdays.Monday;
      // workDays = workDays | Weekdays.Tuesday;

      Console.WriteLine("Tuesday is a workday: {0}", _ 
        System.Convert.ToBoolean(workDays & Weekdays.Tuesday));
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }

  [Flags()]
  public enum Weekdays : int
  {
    Monday = 1,
    Tuesday = 2,
    Wednesday = 4,
    Thursday = 8,
    Friday = 16,
    Saturday = 32,
    Sunday = 64
  }

  public static class Ext
  {
    // Value cannot be passed by reference? 
    public static void Add(this Weekdays Value, Weekdays Arg1) 
    {
      Value = Value | Arg1;
    }
  }
}
```

The `Add` extension method doesn’t work in C# because I can’t use the `ref` keyword. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Just for completion's sake: the correct way to "Add" a value of a flag enum is `Value = Value Or Arg1` unless you want that adding `Monday` two times behaves like adding `Tuesday`. The correct way to remove a flag is `Value = (Value Or Arg1) Xor Arg1`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. In C#, you **cannot** specify any modifiers (like 'out' or `ref`) other than `this` for the first parameter of an extension method - you can for the others. *Not familiar with the VB Syntax but it seems to be using a declarative approach to mark an extension method.*

When you call it, you **do not** specify the first `this` parameter. Hence marking the parameter as out or ref doesnt make sense as You can't specify the modifier when you call it like you'd do for normal methods

```
void MyInstanceMethod(ref SomeClass c, int data) { ... } // definition

obj.MyInstanceMethod(ref someClassObj, 10);              // call

void MyExtensionMethod(this SomeClass c, int data) {.... } // defn

c.MyExtensionMethod(10);                                 // call
```

I think the trouble you're having here is related to value types being immutable. If Weekdays was a reference type, it would work out alright. For immutable types (structs), the defacto way is to return a new instance with the required value. E.g. See the Add method on the struct DateTime, it returns a new DateTime instance whose value = receiver DateTime instance's value + param value.

```
public DateTime Add( TimeSpan value )
```

Comment: In vb, one may specify that an extension method takes the implied `this` (`Me`) as a `ByRef` parameter; unfortunately, the compiler then proceeds to allow read-only structures to be passed to it.  One of the major complaints about mutable value types is that since there's nothing to indicate which methods mutate `this`, they allow such methods to be called uselessly on read-only instances.  I find it odd that the vb.net implementers would decide to allow an extension method that takes a `ByRef` parameter--practically screaming "I WILL MUTATE THE ARGUMENT!"--in a read-only context.

Comment: Since C# 7.2, you're actually allowed to use "ref this" for value types. See  https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/csharp-7.2/readonly-ref.md#refin-extension-methods

Answer (score 11):

Yikes - you're making a mutable immutable struct. It breaks what people expect to see in C#, but if you must, then you can always directly call the method:

```
Ext.Add(ref value, arg1);
```

Any extension method is directly callable.

Also, a clarification:

```
SomeReferenceType value = ...;
SomeReferenceType copy = value;
value.ExtensionMethodByRef(...);
// this failing is semantically ridiculous for reference types, which
// is why it makes no sense to pass a `this` parameter by ref.
object.ReferenceEquals(value, copy);
```

Comment: yep, Eric Lippert would love that ;)

Comment: Enums are immutable values, but passing one by reference as the this parameter to an extension method would make it behave like a mutable value.

Answer (score 5):

Strange that VB.NET allows this and C# doesn't...

However, although it might make sense from a technical point of view (since an extension method is just a static method), I think it doesn't feel right, because extension methods are used as if they were instance methods, and instance methods can't modify the `this` reference.

Comment: In fact instance methods *can* modify "this" in value types. Weird but true.

Comment: It's needless to say that this SUCKS big time for C#.

Comment: @TheoZographos I believe this is the kind of thing that's here to "avoid bad code", as many other things in C# that are more restrictive than, say, C++, and because of them, code is easier to read and maintain. That's what I think they might have thought when they set the limitation in place.