# Redesigning extension method allowing for mutability (for reference types)

Tags: c#, extension-methods, immutability, value-type

I've always used extension methods as immutable and producing a new and improved version of whatever object they performed on.

```
public static ReferenceType Biggify(this ReferenceType self)
{
  return self.Something();
}
```

Now I realize that something it might be nice to have such an extension method do stuff to *self* and not return a jack, like so.

```
public static void Biggify(this ReferenceType self)
{
  self = self.SomethingElse();
}
```

However, I realize that the above operation will only perform on a copy of *self* and the mutation will be discarded as we exit the scope of the method.

1. Can I enable the mutability for the extension method **at all**?

And if so...

2. **How** do I do that?
3. **Should** I do that?

Comment: 1. It depends on whether the `this` parameter is a value or reference type.

Comment: Strings are always immutable, so you can't do this with strings. If it's a reference type though it will work as expected.

Comment: @Jashaszun Put that as a reply, not comment. Also, please note that there's even the question number 3... That's the most interesting part to me. (As for the type, I forgot about the distinction. I'll update the question.)

Comment: There's nothing particular about extension methods here, except that the first parameter cannot be a `ref` parameter.

Comment: Why not just mutate `self` instead of doing assignment if you want it to be mutable?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Good point. I want to perform the operation in the context of extension methods. Should I read into your comment as a negative answer to (3)?

Comment: Okay... so I assume this means you want to do this against a private member you may not have access to? Otherwise, an extension method can mutate the parameter if it wants. (Can't remember if extensions get access to private members)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Yes, that's one scenario. However, the question is asked from an academic curiosity angle. Given that the theoretical "can I" is answered by "kind of" (i.e. reference types), there's the pragmatical consideration of "should I". I myself feel a sense of [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) when I see it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

First (`this`) parameter of extension method can't be `ref` and as result you can't modify reference to passed in object.

Indeed if object itself is mutable extension an easily change the object  explicitly:

```
  void AddCouple<T>(this List<T> list) where T:new()
  {
      list.Add(new T());
      list.Add(new T());
  }
```

or inadvertently like:

```
   List<T> AddToCopy<T>(this List<T> list, T newItem)
   {
       var newList = list;
       newList.Add(newItem); // changed existing list...
       return newList;
   }
```

There some additional discussions in [Doesn't C# Extension Methods allow passing parameters by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259103/doesnt-c-sharp-extension-methods-allow-passing-parameters-by-reference), especially for extensions on immutable types/value types.